# add unique id to php mysql upload

Tags: php, mysql, unique-key

Is there a quick method to add a unique id to a php mysql upload- I have scrolled through these forums but was hoping there is a much simpler method to achieve my aim.

Essentially, I have an upload that works perfectly - and I am hoping to add a product code to each item that will be generated using the auto-incremented unique id field in mysql.

So far I have the following php:

```
<?php include 'dbc.php'; page_protect();

if(!checkAdmin()) {header("Location: login.php");
exit();
}

$host  = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$host_upper = strtoupper($host);
$login_path = @ereg_replace('admin','',dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']));
$path   = rtrim($login_path, '/\\');

foreach($_GET as $key => $value) {
    $get[$key] = filter($value);
}

foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
    $post[$key] = filter($value);
}   
?>

<?php 
if($_FILES['photo']) //check if we uploading a file
{
    $target = "images/furnishings/"; 
    $target = $target . basename( $_FILES['photo']['name']); 

    $title = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['title']); 
    $desc = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['desc']); 
    $price = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['price']);  
    $pandp = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['pandp']);  
    $pic = "images/furnishings/" .(mysql_real_escape_string($_FILES['photo']['name']));
    $productcode = "FUR000" .(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['id']));
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'], $target)) 
{
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO `furnishings` (`title`, `desc`, `price`, `pandp`, `photo`,`productcode`) VALUES ('$title', '$desc', '$price', '$pandp', '$pic', '$productcode')") ;     

    echo "The product has been added to the furnishings category"; 
} 
else 
{ 
    echo "Please fill out the specifications and select the respective file to upload for the main image"; 

}
} 
?>
```

And the following HTML:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="addfurn.php" method="POST">
  <table width="100%" border="2" cellpadding="5"class="myaccount">
   <tr>
       <td>Title: </td>
       <td><input type="text" name="title" /></td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
       <td>Description: </td>
       <td><input type="text" name = "desc" /></td>
     </tr>
          <tr>
       <td>Price: </td>
       <td><input type="text" name = "price" /></td>
     </tr>
        <tr>
       <td>P&amp;P: </td>
       <td><input type="text" name = "pandp" /></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td>Main Image: </td>
       <td><input type="file" name="photo" /></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" class="CMSbutton" value="Add" /></td>
     </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

Now given everything works - the only "problem line" in the code is:

```
$productcode = "FUR000" .(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['id']));
```

assuming that as the id hasnt yet been generated it cannot add it to the insert query - therefore the table in mysql simply returns FUR000 for each new item added.

Is there a way to amend this line to auto-increment in mysql in a similar fashion to the addition of new lines - or do I have to include a unique code for each item in my HTML table?

Any help much appreciated!

Thanks
JD

Comment: what is he talking about, anyone? What is "mysql upload"?

Comment: sorry - php mysql insert.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use [`uniqid`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php), which generates unique ids. I'd recommend using it with more entropy to be on the safe side.

Comment: just what I am after....I need some help incorporating it though! I have included $productcode= printf("uniqid('', true): %s\r\n", uniqid('', true)); into the top of my page, and then used the original insert function:  mysql_query("INSERT INTO `furnishings` (`title`, `desc`, `price`, `pandp`, `photo`,`productcode`) VALUES ('$title', '$desc', '$price', '$pandp', '$pic', '$productcode')") ;  . It is definitely adding something into the table but for some reason its returning a two digit number in mysql - the productcode col type is VARCHAR (255) - could this be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

you need 2 queries for this.

first, insert your data without productcode.
next, get id using mysql_insert_id()
finally, create your productcode and update your table using this newly generated id

however, I see no point in such a field. Why not to create it on the fly?

Comment: having reviewed the uniqid function which I hadnt come across completely agree and looking to create on the fly.

Comment: mysql_insert_id() and an autoincrementing primary key field are the 'proper' way to do things. Generating GUID's for new inserts is more complicated then it need be.

Comment: @JD2011 look. Your productcode field is redundant. 'FUR000' is a constant hardcoded in your script. Id is stored in database. So, you can get your productcode any time you select your data. No need to store it.